# How to Restore backup file(mysql) with java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java project and placed sql file(backup) in this project.
how to Restore this file inside library to mysql with java(Restore of jar file)?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437240/how-can-i-run-a-script-file-using-the-source-command/8438986#8438986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this against a remote server? If you are not opposed to combining Java with the MySQL command line client then you can just do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/mysql <your connection options> < your_sql_backup.sql");
```

If you want it all native Java then you'll end up needing to parse your sql backup and execute the queries through JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Run `mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASWORD SCHEMA <yourfile.sql`. You can use either `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` to execute external program.

The `mysql` command requires redirect to restore data. You can either create shell script/batch file (depending on your operating system) and run it from java or run command line like `cmd /c mysql...` or `/bin/sh mysql` directly from java application (again, depending on your OS)